# Determine if CCLayer is currently rotating

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, rotation, cclayer, ccrotateby

I'm rotating an instance of a `CCLayer` subclass like this:

```
[self runAction:[CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:0.5 angle:180.0]];
```

This rotating is in response to a user tap (which may come rapidly). **How can I determine if the layer is currently being rotating?** In this case I can just ignore the tap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When declaring your CCAction, it is possible to set a tag attribute to it, and then retrieve the action by using getActionByTag. If the returning value is not nil, then it means that the action is actually running.

```
CCRotateBy *rotate = [CCRotateBy actionWithDuration:1.0 angle:100];
rotate.tag = 100;
[myNode runAction:rotate];
if ([myNode getActionByTag:100]) {
    NSLog(@"Rotating!!");
}
```